# Can't make a live USB using Linux subsystem

Tags: linux, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, liveusb, wsl2

I'm trying to install Linux-lite
Tried Rufus but uefi option didn't show up in boot sequence.
So I thought I would use the dd command using Linux bash on Windows.

Obviously `lsblk` doesn't work
So I got the physical-name from PowerShell

```
Get-CimInstance  Win32_DiskDrive | Select Caption,DeviceID,InterfaceType,Size | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceType -eq "USB"}
```

Output

```
Caption                         DeviceID           InterfaceType        Size
-------                         --------           -------------        ----
SanDisk Cruzer Blade USB Device \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 USB           15373048320
```

Which I tried in Linux terminal

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -I \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2
```

But I got this error

```
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open \.PHYSICALDRIVE2: No such file or directory
```

I'm stuck here and I don't know how to move forward with installation.

Comment: 1) Why not use native Windows dd? 2) If you're going to use dd, what are you trying to mkfs now?

Comment: Try [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) on Windows instead of Rufus.

Comment: @user1686 , 1) I didn't know that I can use dd natively on Windows. And I don't know how to use it. Is it the same syntax? 2) Shouldn't I? Is it unnecessary? Either way, it says no such dir so it will yield the same error in dd

Comment: @harrymc , the site doesn't open in my pc. Downloaded it from etcher.net and it downloaded an installer that made a shortcut with no target location (hopefully it's not a malware?). in the end I downloaded from sourceforge. Installed fine but it couldn't flash. It says "failure"

Comment: It’s absolutely not malware

Comment: wsl2 runs inside a virtual machine so obviously it can't access Windows devices directly

Comment: I think you need to do some "bare" `wsl` mounting before you can access the drive with `/dev/sdX` in wsl. Not sure if there will be privilege problem (from the host side) though, especially if you need to write LBA 0 or so. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk

Comment: @phuclv I thought I was outsmarting the system

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded
[linux-lite-5.4-64bit.iso](https://www.linuxliteos.com/download.php)
and used it with
[rufus-3.14](https://rufus.ie/downloads/),
and had no problem with Rufus offering to create a boot media
that works for both BIOS or UEFI:

[image]

If this doesn't work for you, download my versions and try again.

You could also try the
[Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), but Rufus should have worked.

Comment: Shouldn't partition scheme be GPT for uefi?

Comment: @RooTenshi UEFI can boot from MBR without problem. Lots of bootable USBs are formatted in MBR

Answer (score 0):

WSL actually does not understand Windows paths, because it is not merely "Linux commands on Windows" – it is *Linux commands on Linux* running on Windows. (Still true even for WSL1 even though Windows emulates the Linux kernel.) So they only recognize the Linux-like paths that WSL provides them. (I don't know whether WSL provides direct access to disks; check `lsblk`.)

To use Windows device paths such as `\\.\PhysicalDrive2` you need a Windows tool, such as [dd for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd).

*(Additionally, the backslash has a special meaning in Linux shells. Even if the Windows device paths worked in WSL, you would have to specify them in `'quotes'`.)*

Note that the image you're planning to write to the physical drive will just *overwrite* everything that was there before – the files, the filesystem, the partition table, everything. There is therefore no point in creating a new filesystem (mkfs) because dd will just ignore it and you'll get the filesystem that came inside the image anyway.